# How to evaluate state space model?

Tags: model-evaluation, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have a state space model which is basically a Kalman filter. The parameters of the Kalman filter are unknown and are estimated from data using EM algorithm. After I get these parameters, what are some common metrics/methodology to know if this state space model is indeed a good model?

Comment: If you have some data with a known ground truth you can check the estimation precision. Also you can have a look at the innovation and its behavior during estimation.